# PowerShell Script - Cannot Convert Value to Regex

Tags: regex, powershell

Wrote a script for copying files from one folder to another through a regex:

```
param ([string]$dir)

$destination = "Q:\OneDrive\nuget-packages" 
$filter = [regex] "*.nupkg"

$bin = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $filter} 
foreach ($item in $bin) {Copy-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination $destination}
```

Running the script, PowerShell says that it cannot convert value "*.nupkg" to type to type "System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex". Error: "parsing "*.nupkg" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing."

What's wrong with my regex?

Comment: Honestly in your case i would use -Like instead of -Match then you can use wild cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` isn't a wildcard in regex, it's a quantifier, that is something that defines how many times the previous token should occur.

There's no token before your `*`, which is what PowerShell complains about (although it speaks about `{x,y}`, which is another more generic quantifier ; I guess it translates `*` into the equivalent `{0,}` before raising the error).

`\.nupkg$` might do what you want, matching anything that ends in `.nupkg`.

In this regex I don't bother matching the full string, however I use `$` which represents the end of the string. I also escape the `.` to prevent it from being understood as the meta-character it represents in regex.

If you wanted to avoid matching `.nupkg` alone you'd have to match some more of the string, which you could do with `.\.nupkg$`, where `.` is the regex wildcard which will make sure there is at least a single character to match before the extension.